# How to deal with this code about Image Uploader in Android?

Tags: android, image, upload, httpclient

latest update.. i have codes for uploading image.. but i do not know whats going to do for this code..? source code from http://monstercoda.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/android-image-upload-tutorial-part-i/

codes are the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Uri currImageURI;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button gallery_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gallerybtn);
    gallery_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            //to open up a gallery browser
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture.."),1);

            (getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
        }

    });



}

// To handle when an image is selected from the browser
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // currImageURI is the global variable I’m using to hold the content:
            currImageURI = data.getData();
            String s = ("Current image Path is ----->" + getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));
            TextView tv_path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);
            tv_path.setText(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));
        }
 HttpUploader uploader = new HttpUploader();
            try {
                uploader.execute(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));
    }
}

//Convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
public String getRealPathFromURI( Uri contentUri) {
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    android.database.Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri,
            proj,     // Which columns to return
            null,     // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
            null,     // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
            null);     // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String c = cursor.getString(column_index); 
    return c;
}
}
```

my httpUploader is simple as simple as they provide:

```
public class HttpUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

 protected String doInBackground(String... path) {

     String outPut = null;

     for (String sdPath : path) {

         Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath);
         ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

         //Resize the image
         double width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
         double height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
         double ratio = 400/width;
         int newheight = (int)(ratio*height);

         System.out.println("———-width" + width);
         System.out.println("———-height" + height);

         bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, 400, newheight, true);

         //Here you can define .PNG as well
         bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, bao);
         byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
         String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

         String k = "uploading image now ——–" + ba1 ;
         Log.e("k contains", k);

         ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         //store path for image name and id for each profile id.
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", sdPath));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

         try {
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("192.168.1.1/upload.php"); // which request for $_POST['image'];
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();                

             // print responce
             outPut = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
             Log.i("GET RESPONSE—-", outPut);

             //is = entity.getContent();
             Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection");

             bitmapOrg.recycle();

         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("log_tag ******", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
         }
     }
     return outPut;
 }      
 }
```

PHP file saving to the database:

```
 if (isset($base)) {
$base = $_REQUEST["image"];
$filepath = $_REQUEST["path"];
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];

 $image_name = "/image/".$filepath;

 // base64 encoded utf-8 string
 $binary = base64_decode($base);

 // binary, utf-8 bytes

header("Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8");

 $file = fopen($image_name, "wb");

fwrite($file, $binary);

fclose($file);

$result = "UPDATE profile SET image = '$image_name' WHERE RID = '$id'");

if(mysql_affected_rows > 0){
echo json_encode ("success!");
}else{
echo json_encode ("failed!");
}

} else {

die("No POST");
}

?>
```

or if the code is not appropriate... any guidnce can be provided for beginner? there are too many versions of code out there.. and i can slightly understand this because it is simpler than others.

Comment: post your logcat error.

Comment: your image path is null.

Comment: logcat posted T.T any tutorial or guide? or at least with comments..? much appreaciated.. post out there have seperated post. for each file and each part.. we beginners dont know how to stick them up or deal with php.. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.get()` from your `asynctask` call. 
Put `HttpUploader uploader = new HttpUploader();` and `Object image_name = uploader.execute(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));`  without the `.get()` in `onActivityResult()`.  Because only in `onActivityResult()` you know the filename.

Comment: after i remove the .get(). the both catch Exception had been forced remove. but still the same error. after my latest changes in the post.

Comment: After startActivityForResult() there can be no code as you have to wait for the user to choose a picture. So first in onActivityResult() you know the filename and then you start your asynctask.

Comment: raghunandan yes its null, cause i have not choose a picture yet, it forced closed before that..

@greenapps: when i comment out the httpuploader. it allows me to choose pic and displays the picture's URL. but where should i put the httpuploader?

Comment: Do not write `Object image_name = uploader.execute(...);` but only `uploader.execute(...);`. Inplement `onPostExecute()` to do something with `Object`.

Comment: should i just link the htpLoader into the same file as mainActivity? that i can declare pre and post execute

Comment: Link httpLoader? What is that? Leave your HttpUploader class where it is and implement in that class onPreExecute() and onPostExecute().

Comment: okay.. Thanks so far. i've upload the latest version. it has no error for now. working fine but there is nothing happening after the click.. it shows Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection");
my database has not affected.. @.@?

Comment: What shows Log.i outPut? new HttpPost("192.168.1.1/upload.php"); should be `new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1/upload.php");`

Comment: URL changed. Log.i does not appear in log cat.. lol. but no error/warning also... only show path, and the log_tag good connection

Comment: Then make it a Log.e also.

Comment: still does not show it.. i wonder why? means the variable is empty? but if empty, isnt it should show Log.e is error cause empty variable found...